# How to start tezos baking from carthagenet?

Tags: baking, baking-rights

I run baking command from tezos carthagenet with wallet address https://carthagenet.tzstats.com/tz1XexRC24PBspkc9mxrG1AWysibcySQ3i7B
and i get error:

```
Apr 27 09:00:53 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 374677 (max_priority = 64)
```

for this wallet:
https://carthagenet.tzstats.com/tz1gkPz6UKX152USQRQWzCidQgRjcGTyu5FK
equal error

what could be the problem?

Comment: Your account does not qualify to be a baker.  I guess in carthagenet, the same condition as mainnet apply to bake: https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html  For example, the account must own more than 8000XTZ.

Comment: my account has the status of a baker, before that I ran "register as delegate" command with the same balance and it was successful, how can it be executed with insufficient balance for baking?

Answer (score 0):

After registering as a delegate (ie: becoming a baker), you must wait the mandatory 7 cycles before the network grants you baking rights.

That "error" is not an error; This is more of a "notice". It is a typical/normal message that you will see on every block while the baker software runs. This is indicating to you that you do not have any rights for that block below priority 64.